# Minecraft coding error with fabric: Exception while loading entries for entrypoint 'main' provided by 'myfirstmod'

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

```
package net.my.first.mod;

import net.fabricmc.api.ModInitializer;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemGroup;
import net.minecraft.util.Identifier;
import net.minecraft.util.registry.Registry;
import net.minecraft.block.Block;

public class MyFirstMod implements ModInitializer {

    public static final Item FABRIC_ITEM = new FabricItem(new Item.Settings().group(ItemGroup.MISC), null);

    public static final Block FABRIC_BLOCK = new FabricBlock();

    @Override
    public void onInitialize() {
        Registry.register(Registry.ITEM, new Identifier("myfirstmod", "fabric_item"), FABRIC_ITEM);
        Registry.register(Registry.BLOCK, new Identifier("myfirstmod", "fabric_block"), FABRIC_BLOCK);
    }

}
```

```
package net.my.first.mod;

import net.minecraft.entity.player.PlayerEntity;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.util.ActionResult;
import net.minecraft.util.Hand;
import net.minecraft.util.TypedActionResult;
import net.minecraft.world.World;

public class FabricItem extends Item {

    public FabricItem(Settings settings, Settings item$Settings_1) {
        super(item$Settings_1);

    }

    @Override
    public TypedActionResult<ItemStack> use(World world, PlayerEntity playerEntity, Hand hand) {
        return new TypedActionResult<ItemStack>(ActionResult.SUCCESS, playerEntity.getStackInHand(hand));
    }

}
```

I keep running into a crash whenever I try to run my code. I am using visual studio code and I don't understand why this is happening I have even tried re-coding the whole thing. Here's the error I get:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// You should try our sister game, Minceraft!

Time: 27/04/20 18:57
Description: Initializing game

net.fabricmc.loader.api.EntrypointException: Exception while loading entries for entrypoint 'main' provided by 'myfirstmod'
    at net.fabricmc.loader.EntrypointStorage.getEntrypointContainers(EntrypointStorage.java:193)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.FabricLoader.getEntrypointContainers(FabricLoader.java:228)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.entrypoint.minecraft.hooks.EntrypointUtils.invoke0(EntrypointUtils.java:44)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.entrypoint.minecraft.hooks.EntrypointUtils.invoke(EntrypointUtils.java:36)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.entrypoint.minecraft.hooks.EntrypointClient.start(EntrypointClient.java:32)
    at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.<init>(MinecraftClient.java:362)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.game.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:192)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.Knot.init(Knot.java:140)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:26)
    at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main(Main.java:86)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.util.DefaultLanguageAdapter.create(DefaultLanguageAdapter.java:45)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.EntrypointStorage$NewEntry.create(EntrypointStorage.java:114)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.EntrypointStorage$NewEntry.getOrCreate(EntrypointStorage.java:101)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.EntrypointStorage.getEntrypointContainers(EntrypointStorage.java:186)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.minecraft.item.Item$Settings.method_7897(Item.java:369)
    at net.minecraft.item.Item.<init>(Item.java:92)
    at net.my.first.mod.FabricItem.<init>(FabricItem.java:14)
    at net.my.first.mod.MyFirstMod.<clinit>(MyFirstMod.java:12)
    ... 20 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Render thread
Stacktrace:
    at net.fabricmc.loader.EntrypointStorage.getEntrypointContainers(EntrypointStorage.java:193)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.FabricLoader.getEntrypointContainers(FabricLoader.java:228)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.entrypoint.minecraft.hooks.EntrypointUtils.invoke0(EntrypointUtils.java:44)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.entrypoint.minecraft.hooks.EntrypointUtils.invoke(EntrypointUtils.java:36)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.entrypoint.minecraft.hooks.EntrypointClient.start(EntrypointClient.java:32)
    at net.minecraft.client.MinecraftClient.<init>(MinecraftClient.java:362)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.game.MinecraftGameProvider.launch(MinecraftGameProvider.java:192)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.Knot.init(Knot.java:140)
    at net.fabricmc.loader.launch.knot.KnotClient.main(KnotClient.java:26)
    at net.fabricmc.devlaunchinjector.Main.main(Main.java:86)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.15.2
    Minecraft Version ID: 1.15.2
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_251, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 354621680 bytes (338 MB) / 570425344 bytes (544 MB) up to 1895825408 bytes (1808 MB)
    CPUs: 2
    JVM Flags: 3 total; -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:65427,server=n,suspend=y
    Fabric Mods: 
        fabric: Fabric API 0.5.1+build.294-1.15
        fabric-api-base: Fabric API Base 0.1.2+b7f9825d0c
        fabric-biomes-v1: Fabric Biomes (v1) 0.1.5+3b05f68e0c
        fabric-blockrenderlayer-v1: Fabric BlockRenderLayer Registration (v1) 1.1.4+c6a8ea890c
        fabric-commands-v0: Fabric Commands (v0) 0.1.2+b7f9825d0c
        fabric-containers-v0: Fabric Containers (v0) 0.1.3+b7f9825d0c
        fabric-content-registries-v0: Fabric Content Registries (v0) 0.1.3+b7f9825d0c
        fabric-crash-report-info-v1: Fabric Crash Report Info (v1) 0.1.2+b7f9825d0c
        fabric-dimensions-v1: fabric-dimensions-v1 0.3.0+2ad156310c
        fabric-events-interaction-v0: Fabric Events Interaction (v0) 0.3.0+fac69e320c
        fabric-events-lifecycle-v0: Fabric Events Lifecycle (v0) 0.1.2+b7f9825d0c
        fabric-item-groups-v0: Fabric Item Groups (v0) 0.1.6+ec40b2e10c
        fabric-keybindings-v0: Fabric Key Bindings (v0) 0.1.1+dfdb52d60c
        fabric-loot-tables-v1: Fabric Loot Tables (v1) 0.1.5+e08a73050c
        fabric-mining-levels-v0: Fabric Mining Levels (v0) 0.1.1+b7f9825d0c
        fabric-models-v0: Fabric Models (v0) 0.1.0+dfdb52d60c
        fabric-networking-blockentity-v0: Fabric Networking Block Entity (v0) 0.2.3+e08a73050c
        fabric-networking-v0: Fabric Networking (v0) 0.1.7+12515ed90c
        fabric-object-builders-v0: Fabric Object Builders (v0) 0.1.3+e4c9a9c30c
        fabric-particles-v1: fabric-particles-v1 0.1.1+dfdb52d60c
        fabric-registry-sync-v0: Fabric Registry Sync (v0) 0.2.6+f3d8141b0c
        fabric-renderer-api-v1: Fabric Renderer API (v1) 0.2.10+f08b61330c
        fabric-renderer-indigo: Fabric Renderer - Indigo 0.2.23+9290e2ed0c
        fabric-renderer-registries-v1: Fabric Renderer Registries (v1) 2.0.1+5a0f9a600c
        fabric-rendering-data-attachment-v1: Fabric Rendering Data Attachment (v1) 0.1.3+b7f9825d0c
        fabric-rendering-fluids-v1: Fabric Rendering Fluids (v1) 0.1.6+12515ed90c
        fabric-rendering-v0: Fabric Rendering (v0) 1.1.0+534104900c
        fabric-rendering-v1: Fabric Rendering (v1) 0.1.0+534104900c
        fabric-resource-loader-v0: Fabric Resource Loader (v0) 0.1.10+06c939b30c
        fabric-tag-extensions-v0: Fabric Tag Extensions (v0) 0.1.3+abd915800c
        fabric-textures-v0: Fabric Textures (v0) 1.0.4+821cdba70c
        fabricloader: Fabric Loader 0.8.2+build.194
        minecraft: Minecraft 1.15.2
        myfirstmod: My First Mod ${version}
    Launched Version: Fabric
    Backend library: LWJGL version 3.2.2 build 10
    Backend API: NO CONTEXT
    GL Caps: 
    Using VBOs: Yes
    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fabric'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    CPU: <unknown>
```

Comment: You need to post your code, in particular `MyFirstMod.java` and `FabricItem.java`.

Comment: Your error starts with a NullPointerException which probably means you're referencing a variable that hasn't been initialized. This variable is probably in the initialization method of net.my.first.mod.FabricItem, and the error then causes an ExceptionInInitializerError when Fabric tries to load the class. Of course, I can't actually be sure of anything since you didn't post any of your code as @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica pointed out. Please refer to the meta post on making your first post to avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 2):

You're throwing away the real `Settings` you have and passing `null` instead! Change this:

```
    public FabricItem(Settings settings, Settings item$Settings_1) {
        super(item$Settings_1);

    }
```

To this:

```
    public FabricItem(Settings settings, Settings item$Settings_1) {
        super(settings);

    }
```

You can also get rid of the second parameter both from that definition and from where you call it in `MyFirstMod`, now that you're not using it for anything.